# Transfer code from App to WiFi module

Tags: ios, xcode, network-programming

The app I am working on is to control model trains. The train manufacturer has provided the code that would operate the train (for example, ring bell, move forward, etc.).

The WiFi module I would use for the app broadcasts a WiFi Network. In the Settings section of the iPad, the WiFi network can be located and connected to without the need of a password.

I need to figure out how my app can connect to that same WiFi network. From there each button on the app would be programmed to the specific manufacturer provided code. For example, the bell button has a specific code that when pressed that code is sent from the iPad to the WiFi module by way of the WiFi network. The the WiFi module is connected to a Command Base by way of a serial port. So the WiFi module sends the code to the Command Base. The Command Base then sends the code through 2.4Ghz frequency to the train where in our example it will ring its bell.

Any suggestions to programming the buttons & connecting to the WiFi network is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The only way for the iPad to connect to the wireless network is for the user to go into the settings app and do it themselves. There is no way for your app to change the network.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow you to change system settings like wifi network with your app. You simply need to instruct the user. You CAN provide them a link to the settings page however:

```
NSURL* settingsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@”prefs:root=WIFI”]]; // objective c
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:settingsURL];

let settingsURL = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=WIFI") // swift
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(settingsURL)
```